# MissingComponentException

Tags: c#, unity3d

La pelotita da en la barra indestructible, rebota bien, y en el contador debería quitar un digito al contador, pero en vez de eso me sale este mensaje.

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the
>   "objeto" game object, but a script is trying to acces it.

Aquí mi código por encima:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision cacharro)
{       
    for(toque = 5;toque <= 5; toque++)
    {
        toques.text = toque.ToString();
    }
}
```

algún alma caritativa que me explique porque no me funciona.

Comment: es un juego de esos de tirar una pelota a unas barras que estan en lo alto del escenario, todo me funciona, pero sigo sin entender porque me sale este mensaje y no descuenta en el contador.

Comment: Simplemente no has asignado el TextMesh; reviza cuidadosamente tu código.